# Fastest way to build a searchable object that associates strings with numbers

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to associate strings with numbers in MATLAB. That is, I want to create an object that takes the form

```
string: 'abcd', index: 1
string: 'abdd', index: 2
etc.
```

The thing is, I need to be able to search the object when provided with a string, for example, 'abcd' and get it to return the associated (unique) index, 1 in this case. I also need to be able to search the object using an index and get it to return the associated string. New elements will need to be added to this object fairly frequently. There will be many elements in this object (on the order of 500000). The strings themselves are not 'ordered' in general (if such a thing would even help).

**Question:** What is the fastest way to do this in MATLAB?

---

**What I've tried:** It seems like the Map class in MATLAB is relevant; however, I can't figure out how to search in both directions. What I mean by that is illustrated in the following example provided on the Mathworks website:

```
ticketMap = containers.Map(...
{'2R175', 'B7398', 'A479GY', 'NZ1452'}, ...
{'James Enright', 'Carl Haynes', 'Sarah Latham', ...
 'Bradley Reid'});
ticketMap('2R175') -> returns James Enright
```

But it seems that searching in the other direction is not supported, that is, given 'James Enright' get it to return '2R175'. I've also tried the Map2 code (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40323-map2-enhanced-map-class) but it is very slow.

Comment: Have you thought about putting your strings in a cell array and using the indices of the cell array as your index? You could easily search the cell array with `is member`.

Comment: Have you tried creating 2 map objects, A -> B and BB -> AA, where AA is a copy of AA and B is a copy of BB at each insertion/deletion of key-map pair. In that case, you might need an extra attribute of each string that can tell you which map-object you need to search.

Comment: try to use database when you have such large amount of data,with database you could add,search or delete data from your table , it is fast and reliable and its implementation is not so hard ,  (two map solution is good if you dont like to use databases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the best solution is building two maps, one map from ticket to name, and one map from name to ticket.

Example:

```
tickets = {'2R175', 'B7398', 'A479GY', 'NZ1452'};
names = {'James Enright', 'Carl Haynes', 'Sarah Latham', 'Bradley Reid'};

ticketMap = containers.Map(tickets, names);

namesMap = containers.Map(names, tickets);
%ticketMap('2R175') -> returns James Enright
%namesMap('James Enright') -> 2R175
```

Creating and managing two maps may seem as waste of memory, and computation time, but [time-time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), it's the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine the fastest solution is an object with limited error checking that keeps a cell array of the character arrays and an associated index array.  Then a combination of simple indexing and `strcmp` can be used to pull either-or as needed.

Here's a quick example of such an object (using lexical closures because I like them and have seen better performance in the past, which may not be true these days).

```
function store = makeStringMap(strings)

    if (nargin >= 1) && not(isempty(strings))
        if iscellstr(strings) 
            strings = strings(:);
        elseif ischar(strings)
            strings = cellstr(strings);
        else
            error('makeStringStore:wrongInputType',...
                'First input ''strings'' must be either a cellstr or a char array.');
        end
    else
        strings = {};
    end

    nstrings = numel(strings);
    indices  = 1:nstrings;

    store.append = @(string) append(string);
    function [] = append(string)
        if ischar(string)
            string = cellstr(string);
        end
        nstring  = numel(string)                        ;
        strings  = [strings;string]                     ;
        indices  = [indices,(1+nstrings)+(0:(nstring-1))]   ;
        nstrings = indices(end)                         ;
    end

    store.getStringByIndex = @(index) getStringByIndex(index);
    function string = getStringByIndex(index)
        if all(index>0 && index<=nstrings)
            string = strings(index);
        end
    end

    store.getIndexByString = @(string) getIndexByString(string);
    function index = getIndexByString(string)
        if ischar(string)
            string = cellstr(string);
        end
        nstring = numel(string);
        index = zeros(nstring,1);
        for k = 1:nstring
            index = indices(strcmp(strings,string{k}));
        end
    end

    store.getStrings = @() getStrings();
    function out = getStrings()
        out = strings;
    end
end
```

A simple test run:

```
>> s = makeStringMap(char(randi([97,122],5,10)));
>> s.getStrings()
ans = 
    'yheepozpvs'
    'kkdrslqcic'
    'smktndqhjg'
    'nfqikjtsbb'
    'jpfgtdlbem'
>> s.getStringByIndex(2)
ans = 
    'kkdrslqcic'
>> s.getIndexByString(s.getStringByIndex(2))
ans =
     2
>> s.append(char(randi([97,122],3,10)));
>> s.getStringByIndex(7)
ans = 
    'tajrjqmikg'
>> s.getIndexByString(s.getStringByIndex(7))
ans =
     7
```

I'll note that while I do use the variable `string` a lot, it is not the new `string` class since I'm running R2016a and still use `char` and `cellstr` a lot.